# Konva/Typescript - Version update from 2.5.1 to 6.0.0 gives compilation errors "index-types has no exported member 'Rect/Node/Shape/group'."

Tags: angular, typescript, konvajs, konva

We are using Konva with our Angular project and in typescript we used it like...

```
import * as Konva from 'konva';
...
private _stage: Konva.Stage;
...
this._stage = new Konva.Stage();
...
const box: Konva.Rect;
const boxShape: Konva.Shape;
```

I have updated the version of Konva from 2.5.1 to 6.0.0 and when I build the project it gives me compile time errors like below for all objects of Konva...

> error TS2694: Namespace
> '".../node_modules/konva/lib/index-types"'
> has no exported member 'Rect'.

> error TS2694: Namespace
> '".../node_modules/konva/lib/index-types"'
> has no exported member 'Node'.

> error TS2694: Namespace
> '".../node_modules/konva/lib/index-types"'
> has no exported member 'Shape'.

Application Details:-

`Typescript version - "4.0.7".`
`Angular version - "10.2.5".`
`typescript targets "es2015"`

**EDIT**

I have observed that in previous version it used to add `Konva.d.ts` file as typeDefinitions for typescript but in this version it doesn't add it anymore and instead it adds `index-types.d.ts` which doesn't have few types like `SizeConfig`

I have changed import statement
`import * as Konva from 'konva';`
to
`import Konva from 'konva';`

Even after changing this, I am still getting compile time errors for the types which are not available in `index-types.d.ts`

I am still missing something.
I will keep updating the question with my findings.

**EDIT-2**

For Compile time errors for the types...

There used to be types like `Rect{x1:number, y1:number, x2:number, y2:number}` which they have removed from their type definition file `index-types.d.ts` as they were no longer using it.

I had used those types in our code so we just created new types in our code which were missing in `index-types.d.ts` and I was able to build it successfully.

Note - This is the first time I am asking question so pardon me if I haven't done it in proper way.

Comment: Maybe there is something in your tsconfig that messes with the module resolution?

Comment: @MikhailDudin - 
Thanks for reply and pardon me for very late reply.
I Used workaround by creating missing types in our code as those types were no longer required in Konva library but in our code we were still using it. So we created our own.